# Android: Change activity with input user

Tags: java, android, android-activity, calendar, device

In my project I have 2 activities. In the main activity I have text input, where the user enters his data. Pressing the "calendar" button enters a second activity where I have to select the day the user needs. Once you have chosen the day, return to the main activity. How can I go back without the inserted text being deleted?

Main activity to second activity

```
 setData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this,CalendarActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
       }
  });
```

Second activity

```
 calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

             i1 = i1 + 1;
             String f = i2 + " / " + i1 +" / " + i;
             text.setText(f);
             data = new Data(i2,i1,i);
             //ritorna in AddActivity

        }
   });
```

Comment: Plz make your question clear. Do send the xml files and java code of the activities so that it can be made clear which activities contain which fileds.

Comment: which "inserted text" you want to retain?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain user entered data in MainActivity, when coming back from SecondActivity.

Try to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

Ex:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityToStart);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
startActivity(intent);
```

or Else handle it by using `startActivityforResult`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityToStart);
startActivityforResult(intent,111);
```